# Azure Cognititve search API connection timeout

Tags: .net, azure, rest, azure-search-.net-sdk

Created a sample azure search service and imported sample data for the same, able to get data using azure cognitive search API from Postman but getting following exception

> '
>   SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   '

```
internal async Task<string> Getresult()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("api-key", adminApiKey);
    var result = await client.GetAsync(searchServiceName);//line where exception occurs
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return resultContent;
}
```

Modified code

```
internal async Task<Hotel> Getresult(string search)
{
    SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceName, "hotels-sample-index", new SearchCredentials(adminApiKey));
    var results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("*");
    return results;
}
```

gets error

> 'cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.DocumentSearchResult' to 'Models.Hotel'
>   '

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Azure Cognitive Search API. It's much easier:

1-Install Package Microsoft.Azure.Search

```
SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceName, indexName, new SearchCredentials(queryApiKey));

ISearchIndexClient indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName);

var results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("motel", parameters);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk

Comment: installed and added code gets this error **cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.DocumentSearchResult<Models.Hotel>' to 'Models.Hotel'**

Comment: this was a sample ....you should convert the json to the document type that is stored in your Azure Cognitive Search Index